# How do I edit or import CSS in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to React and I seem to have a problem with CSS loading. I tried to import it according to the tutorial, but that doesn't seem to be a good way to do it now, because the tutorial is a bit older. Here's my code, I hope someone can help.

Why isn't my CSS loading? What should I do?

Layout.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Aux from "../../hoc/Auxx";
import classes from './Layout.css'

const layout = (props) => (
  <Aux>
    <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
    <main className={classes.Content}>{props.children}</main>
  </Aux>
);

export default layout;
```

Layout.css

```
.Content{
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using webpack? How are your style- and css loaders defined? You can rename `Layout.css` to `Layout.module.css` and it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just import it normally

```
import './Layout.css'
```

and use the classes like you do in a normal css

```
const layout = (props) => (
  <Aux>
    <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
    <main className={"Content"}>{props.children}</main>
  </Aux>
);
```

Comment: I will as soon as time for that expires, I can't do it yet :)